# jQuery $(this).attr('id') returns null

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have an image in a table on a web page.  The image has an id of "0055" and the cell it inhabits has the id "0055Thumb". If I add the following code in my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#0055').click(function(){
    click0055();
})
})

function click0055()
{
    $('#main').attr("src", "/images/Levi/518/11518_0055_BlackPressed_Front.png");
    var curID = $(this).attr('id');

    alert(curID);
}
```

shouldn't alert(curID) return either "0055Thumb" or "0055"?  I'm trying to get the objects id so I can pass it to another function.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `window` doesn't have an id attribute.

Comment: `this` in your function isn't what you think it is, as it's not called the right way.

Comment: `console.log(this)` inside of your `click0055()` to see what they're talking about.

Answer (score 6):

Just try with:

```
$('#0055').click(click0055);
```

If you call `click0055` from an anonymous function binded to the `click` event it loses context which is passed with the above method. Alternative way is to do it with [`jQuery.proxy`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
$('#0055').click(function(){
  $.proxy(click0055, this)();
});
```

Comment: or `click0055.call(this);` (or `.apply`)

Comment: @hsz you forgot to execute the proxied function.

Answer (score 1):

When you call a function, it doesn't inherit the context from the calling code. In the function `this` is no longer a reference to the element where the event happened.

Pass the reference along to the function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#0055').click(function(){
    click0055(this);
  })
})

function click0055(el) {
  $('#main').attr("src", "/images/Levi/518/11518_0055_BlackPressed_Front.png");
  var curID = $(el).attr('id');
  alert(curID);
}
```

Alternatively, use the `call` method to specify the context for the function call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#0055').click(function(){
    click0055.call(this);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass $(this) as parameter: http://jsfiddle.net/hTfU7/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#0055').click(function(){
    click0055($(this));
})
})

function click0055($thisIsMe)
{
    $('#main').attr("src", "/images/Levi/518/11518_0055_BlackPressed_Front.png");
    var curID = $thisIsMe.attr('id');

    alert(curID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is what "this" means in the scope you are calling it.
Here a jsfiddle with the fix:

http://jsfiddle.net/MZdMM/

If you really need to nest that function inside the anonimous function is ok, but keep a reference of what "this" is by passing the argument into the nested function.

```
function click0055(elem){
    $('#main').attr("src", "/images/Levi/518/11518_0055_BlackPressed_Front.png");
    var curID = $(elem).attr('id');

    alert(curID);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#0055').on("click",function(){
        var elem = this;
        click0055(elem);
        // Let's say here is more code ...
    });
});
```